# Significato di "in seconda ipotesi"

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> «Ti posso fare una domanda?» 
>          «Sentiamo.» 
>          «Non è stato perché avevi poca voglia di lavorare?» 
>          «**In seconda ipotesi**, sì. Voglio lavorare in altra maniera.» 
>          «È vero che vuoi fare lo scrittore?» 
>          «Voglio fare il giornalista.»

Si tratta di un dialogo tra Vasco Pratolini e il suo fratello, che ha chiesto all'autore perché ha fatto ricoverare la nonna in Ospizio, domanda a cui Vasco ha fornito una spiegazione.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "in seconda ipotesi"? Ho cercato il termine "ipotesi" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessun riferimento a questa espressione.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prendo la definizione della Treccani di *ipotesi*:

> Spiegazione logica, fondata su indizî e congetture, che si dà provvisoriamente di un fatto o di una serie di fatti, noti o accertabili in sé ma non nelle loro cause, nei loro processi, ecc.

Secondo me il senso del dialogo qui è che il personaggio che pronuncia questa frase (Vasco Pratolini) non sa spiegare al fratello e nemmeno a se stesso il suo comportamento per cui la spiegazione di questo va cercata nel campo delle congetture.

In ordine di importanza, questa spiegazione è il voler lavorare in modo diverso, e come possibilità secondaria - o parziale -  il fatto di aver poca voglia di lavorare.

È anche possibile che *"seconda"* sia da intendersi in ordine temporale, per cui avrebbe proprio lo stesso significato di "ripensandoci".

Comment: +1, ma sei sicuro che “in seconda battuta” venga dalla dattilografia? Secondo il Treccani viene dal calcio.

Comment: In effetti, no non ne sono affatto sicuro :)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  Ho aggiunto una spiegazione al testo della domanda per fornire un po' più di contesto.

Comment: @charo aggiornata

Answer (score 0):

Penso sia un’altra maniera per dire:

> ripensandoci:
>
> - riconsiderando; in ulteriore considerazione. Ho inizialmente pensato che fosse una buona idea, ma a pensarci bene, non sono così sicuro.